# C#: How to load Cursor from Resource file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have imported a file "x.ani" into Resource file Resources.resx. Now trying to load that file using ResourceManager.GetObject("aero_busy.ani")

```
Cursor.Current = (Cursor)ResourcesX.GetObject("aero_busy.ani");
```

but it didn't work .. (certainly) :)

How can I change the current Cursor using resource object?

Comment: The Cursor class does not support animated cursors. As in my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't found any better way than dumping to a temp file and use the Win32 load cursor from file method. The hack goes something like this (I removed a big chunk of boilerplate code for clarity, in which a temp file is written with the data from the stream). Also, all exception handling etc. was removed.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(String str);

public static Cursor LoadCursorFromResource(string resourceName)
{         
     Stream cursorStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);        

     // Write a temp file here with the data in cursorStream

     Cursor result = new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(tempFile));
     File.Delete(tempFile);

     return result.
}
```

You would use this as (remember namespaces when loading embedded resources).

```
Cursors.Current = LoadCursorFromResource("My.Namespace.Filename");
```

Comment: With regard to the comment & answer from Jethro, I have only used .cur (non-animated) cursors with this method. This method should allow colored cursors though.

Comment: thank you for the valuable response :) I just wanted my program to be a portable one (call a stub program too) I mean only an Exe file has to be copied. However your suggestions are worth implementation :) thanks again.

Comment: I confirm that this code works with colored cursors. Whereas [the alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897793/199364) of putting the bytes into a memory stream (rather than a file) does not work.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' - this answer *does* only require an exe file. The cursors *are* embedded as resources in that file. You just need some folder in which you are allowed to create temporary files. For example, `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Answer (score 20):

I do it by adding the cursor .cur file into the Resources part of the project (I am using Visual Studio). I'm not sure if it would have to be .cur, so long as the development program can load it.

Having done that in the variables declaration part of my code I create a MemoryStream from the cursor file:

```
private static System.IO.MemoryStream cursorMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myCurrentProject.Properties.Resources.myCursorFile);
```

...and then you can create the cursor from the MemoryStream:

```
private Cursor newCursor = new Cursor(cursorMemoryStream);
```

You can then assign the cursor as you like within the program, e.g.

```
pictureBox1.Cursor = newCursor;
```

and the new cursor is compiled as part of the program.

Comment: I think this way is better than others!

Comment: I confirm GorillaApe's comment. This answer, using a memory stream, does not work with 32-bit color.  For color, use [Anders approach reading bytes from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897405/199364).

Answer (score 6):

after a few turns to the issue, I find the elegant solution is:

```
internal static Cursor GetCursor(string cursorName)
    {
        var buffer = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(cursorName) as byte[];

        using (var m = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return new Cursor(m);
        }
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: All answers based on MemoryStream will work for black & white cursors, but don't support 32-bit color cursors. Hopefully Microsoft will correct this someday, so we can go back to techniques like this. Until then, it is necessary, for color cursors, to use `new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(..))` rather than a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue has to do with the fact that the cursor must have .cur extension in order to be used as Cursor.

// The following generates a cursor from an embedded resource.

// To add a custom cursor, create or use an existing 16x16 bitmap
//        1. Add a new cursor file to your project: 
//                File->Add New Item->Local Project Items->Cursor File
//        2. Select 16x16 image type:
//                Image->Current Icon Image Types->16x16

The above was taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Update : Found the answer why.

"Note Note

The Cursor class does not support animated cursors (.ani files) or cursors with colors other than black and white."

Found [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time and Response :) 
+1 for significant tips :)

Comment: UPDATE: Despite that comment in the docs (still shown today in .Net 4.7.2 docs), Cursor class now *does* (partly) support color cursors. See [Anders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897405/199364).

Answer (score 1):

Writing a file to disk then importing it as a cursor is impractical, there is simpler solution. Convert your .cur to .ico and import your cursor as an icon resource. Then you can simply do:

```
Cursor c = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.mycursor.Handle);
```

This will support 32 bit colors properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string str);

    Cursor SetCursor(byte[] resourceName)
    {
        string tempPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp.cur";
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, resourceName);
        Cursor result = new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(tempPath));
        File.Delete(tempPath);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please only write an answer if it shows something new, not covered by other answers. This technique was shown 7 years earlier, in the accepted answer.

Comment: I get a CS1503 error shown. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UZ5W.png

Answer (score 0):

Pulling it all together...

This is a combination of the strongly typed resources Visual Studio now provides, plus Win32 LoadCursorFromFile (via [Anders original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897274/c-how-to-load-cursor-from-resource-file/6897405#6897405) using manifest resource loads).

I also threw in a cache of instantiated cursors, because that's appropriate for my app. Nuke that if you don't need it.

```
namespace Draw
{
/// <summary>
/// Controls use of all the cursors in the app, supports loading from strongly typed resources, and caches all references for the lifetime of the app.
/// </summary>
public static class Cursors
{
    // Cache of already loaded cursors
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], Cursor> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], Cursor>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a cursor given the appropriate id from Resources.Designer.cs (auto-generated from Resources.resx). All cursors are
    /// cached, so do not Dispose of the cursor returned from this function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cursorResource">The resource of the cursor to load. e.g. Properties.Resources.MyCursor (or byte array from .cur or .ani file)</param>
    /// <returns>The cursor. Do not Dispose this returned cursor as it is cached for the app's lifetime.</returns>
    public static Cursor GetCursor(byte[] cursorResource)
    {
        // Have we already loaded this cursor? Use that.
        if (cache.TryGetValue(cursorResource, out Cursor cursor))
            return cursor;

        // Get a temporary file
        var tmpFile = Utils.GetTempFile();

        try
        {
            // Write the cursor resource to temp file
            File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, cursorResource);

            // Read back in from temp file as a cursor. Unlike Cursor(MemoryStream(byte[])) constructor, 
            // the Cursor(Int32 handle) version deals correctly with all cursor types.
            cursor = new Cursor(Win32.LoadCursorFromFile(tmpFile));

            // Update dictionary and return
            cache.AddOrUpdate(cursorResource, cursor, (key, old) => cursor);
            return cursor;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Remove the temp file
            Utils.TryDeleteFile(tmpFile);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Example call:

```
Cursor = Draw.Cursors.GetCursor(Properties.Resources.Cursor_ArrowBoundary);
```