# Increase Cursor Size on Entire Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, mouse-cursor

First of all, please put aside notions of "Your application shouldn't do this". This is exactly what the people purchasing this software will be expecting.

How can I, system-wide, increase the size of the mouse cursor? I'd have to increase all mouse cursors too, so I don't think [SetCursor](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursor) would do the trick, at least not in any nice, clean way.

And I can't use the Form's Cursor Size as [detailed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.size%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as this would only affect the cursor when it's active on the form.

I see that there are "Extra Large" Mouse Cursors available in Windows' Ease-of-Access Centre, so there must be a way...

Any ideas?

Comment: See SetSystemCursor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395.aspx. Also See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897274/c-how-to-load-cursor-from-resource-file

Comment: Why don't you just use the Extra Large mouse cursors?

Comment: What other applications are your users going to be interacting with?

Comment: @DavidHefferman I would use those, if I could set them in code myself. If Extra Large is as Large as it gets, that's fine with me.

Comment: @Charlie They'll typically just be putting videos and maybe firefox/chrome on the desktop. They'l however be interacting with this PC from far away, hence the need for a larger cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution to this is going to get really hairy because of two things:
 1. Any application can change the cursor to anything else on its own
 2. Cursors are at most 32x32 pixels

If an application changes the cursor to something that is 32x32 pixels, there's no way to make that any larger.

The Extra Large cursors are just just using more of the 32x32 pixels a cursor can use. The default ones are just using the top-left more-or-less quadrant of the 32x32.

You might be able to constantly Retrieve the current cursor using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648388(v=vs.85).aspx

and then paint ontop of all windows that cursor doubled in size by stretching the image, then set the cursor to some empty cursor file. This is horribly hacky and will likely cause tons of flickering and compatibility problems.