# how to use custom cursor in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have cursor.cur in my.resources.cursor

but it doesn't work

then i tried icon it does work but when cursor is above buttons it needs to take alot above to click it

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim mycursor As Icon = My.Resources.normal ' normal is my curosor icon
        Me.Cursor = New Cursor(mycursor.Handle)
    End Sub
```

anybody can help me with working code
i would also love if anybody can do this same by invoking win32

Comment: We probably need to know more about your icon.  Presumably, a cursor would work better though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How to load Cursor from Resource file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897274/c-how-to-load-cursor-from-resource-file)

Comment: it is in c# i cant convert it to vb.net i tried online converters gives errors

Answer (score 0):

Note you said that `My.Resources.cursor` is the Class.

Since it's a cursor file and not an icon file, try this:

```
Imports System

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myCursor As New Cursor(New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.cursor.cursor)) 'Exception here indicates a 32bpp cursor.
End Sub
```

This, however, doesn't work with 32 bit-per-pixel cursors. I recommend 24bpp.

That also makes your cursor black and white.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class ResxCursor
    Private Declare Function LoadCursorFromFile Lib "user32" Alias "LoadCursorFromFileA" (
 ByVal lpFileName As String) As IntPtr

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal initialData As ResxCursor) As Cursor
        Dim ExtractDIR As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(".")
        Dim ExtractPath As String = ExtractDIR + initialData._Cursor.GetHashCode.ToString
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(ExtractPath, initialData._Cursor)
        Dim CL As IntPtr = LoadCursorFromFile(ExtractPath)
        IO.File.Delete(ExtractPath)
        Return New Cursor(CL)
    End Operator
    Protected Friend _Cursor As Byte()
    Sub New(Cursor As Byte())
        _Cursor = Cursor
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Usage:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Button1.Cursor = New ResxCursor(My.Resources.MainFormResource.aero_pen)
End Sub
```

---

[Reference Link](https://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?571105-%D8%AA%D8%BA%DB%8C%DB%8C%D8%B1-Cursor-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%AA)