# Setting custom cursor over a Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I'm creating a WinForms application in Visual C#, and would like to change the cursor to a custom image (.cur) that I created. I want the cursor image to change to this over the form window only.

All previously answered questions suggest setting `this.cursor` to a new `cursor` object created with the path to the cursor, with statements like these:

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(@"C:\green.cur"); // this
this.Cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), @"C:\green.cur"); // or this
```

but both statements result in the same error :

> Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted.

I've also tried importing the cursor with `LoadImage` after importing `user32.dll` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077113/2874693) but this resulted in the error :

> Win32 handle passed to Cursor is not valid or is the wrong type.

I'm able to set the cursor to the standard wait cursor with the following statement :

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

The same .cur file works perfectly when used to set the cursor in a C++ program where the cursor is embedded in a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LoadCursorFromFile`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);
```

and when you want to change your cursor:

```
IntPtr cursor = LoadCursorFromFile(@"C:\green.cur");
this.Cursor = new Cursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to restrict the cursor size to 32 * 32. Is there any way I could load a larger cursor? The .cur file is currently 128 * 128.

Comment: To change the size you need to use the method `SetSystemCursor` which will change the cursor of the computer **not only your program**. Are you sure that this is what you wise for?

Comment: No, I want it changed just over the program. LoadImage does this in C++, and has parameters to set the cursor size ( and also resizes the cursor if necessary ). I was wondering if you could find some way to resize the cursor without using LoadImage, or tell me what could possibly be wrong with using LoadImage as I have. Thanks.